# Unity change image of child component of button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Start () {
    foreach (Sprite texture in spriteImages) {
        GameObject button = Instantiate (shopButtonPrefab) as GameObject;
        button.GetComponentInChildren<Image>().sprite = texture;
        button.transform.SetParent (shopButtonContrainer.transform, false);

    }
}
```

I have a button prefab, that is a button, with an image component as a child. I'm not sure why my code changes the buttons sprite image in opposition to the childs'. It is important that I change the child, the image I am changing it too is a circle, so I don't want to lose the rectangle default image the button already is. How can I change the child image, whilst leaving the button image as default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetComponentInChildren<t>()` gets the requested component in the gameobject or it's children using a depth first search, this means it will check the parent object first, and return the first instance it finds.  You can use `GetComponentsInChildren<t>()` this will return an array all of components found in the parent and it's children.

An alternative would be to get the first child element, and call `GetComponent<t>()` on that child.

To skip the parent, Using `GetComponentsInChildren<t>()` loop through all the found components and if they aren't the `t` on the parent then change its texture.

Here is an example, it isn't exactly the most efficient way to do it:

```
void Start () {

    foreach (Sprite texture in spriteImages) {
        GameObject button = Instantiate (shopButtonPrefab) as GameObject;
        Image buttonImage= button.GetComponent<Image>();
        Image[] images = button.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>().sprite = texture;
        foreach(Image image in images) {
            if(image != buttonImage) 
            {
                image.sprite = texture;
                break;
            }
        }
        button.transform.SetParent (shopButtonContrainer.transform, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some more reading: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html

Comment: So how can I make it skip the parent?

Comment: You cannot make that function skip the parent, however the last line of my answer gives you an alternative way to get the image on the child.

Comment: Completely missed that. Because I'm fairly new to all this, what would the if statement in my for loop be to check if it's on the parent? Thanks!

Comment: That's done it! Thank you so much. Out of interest, is the break necessary?

Comment: @Mattattack depends on your hierchy, I don't know if you have multiple children with Image on them either, so if you dont then no.

Comment: I missed that part @Eddge \*salute\*